# Rails4 mysql table about polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used rails4.2.8, now I had the problem about how to create the polymorphic tables in mysql, The questions tags classifies tables relations is like this :

[image]

Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a polymorphic table for this

create a table **taggables** with 2 columns `question_id` and `tag_id`

add `classify_id` to **questions** table
add `classify_id` to **tags** table

then update your models with

```
class Question
  has_many :taggables
  has_many :tags, through: :taggables
  belongs_to :classify
end

class Tag
  has_many :taggables
  has_many :questions, through: :taggables
  belongs_to :classify
end

class Taggable
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Classify
  has_many :questions
  has_many :tags
end
```

Comment: Hi , @Pavittar Gill , `<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %> ` ,  ` <%= f.select :classify, options_for_classify, {}, class: "form-control" %> ` , in this code , how could I make the `f.select` to choose `classify` from `classify.rb `  model? Thanks so much.

Comment: try `= f.select :classify_id, options_for_select(Classify.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }, @question.classify_id), include_blank: true`